# Unexpected token when importing an interface in svelte and running vitest

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, vitest

I'm very new to svelte and TS, I'm trying to do a simple import and when I run vitest is fails with the following error

```
Unexpected token
 1 |  <script lang="ts">
 2 |    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
 3 |    import type { Choice } from './../../types';
                    ^
 4 |    export let choices: Choice[]
 5 |    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher<{handleChooseEvent: String}>();
```

The code complies and runs as expected on localhost but trying to write a test is causing the error.

this is my types.ts

```
// Define the Choice interface
export interface Choice {
    text: String;
    id: Number;
    nextScene?: String; //? makes it optional
}
```

chatgtp told me to us this types.ts, I'm not sure if this is the right approach

I verified that typescript is installed, and added it to my vite.config.ts

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(), // Keep the SvelteKit plugin
        typescript()
    ],
    test: {
        include: ['**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});
```

and this is my vitetest.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      svelte({
        hot: !process.env.VITEST,
        preprocess: [sveltePreprocess({ typescript: true })] // <-- this line allow vitest to parse svelte component using typescript
      }),
      typescript()
    ],
    test: {
      include: ['imports/**/*.vitest.{js,ts}'],
      globals: true,
      environment: 'jsdom',
    },
  })
```

I also verified that typescript is in my package.json